# Is it a good method to save arrays in a list?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to learn python and by starting i thought to impliment polynomial curve fitting with square error function.So the next list is the coefficient of the numpy.polyfit function with order of polynomial from 0 to 4:

```
[array([-0.01819394]), array([-1.40744691,  0.68552951]), array([ 0.80998048, -2.21742739,  0.80552662]), array([ 22.23999663, -32.55001446,  10.44015094,   0.03673661]), array([ -2.85384060e+00,   2.79476778e+01,  -3.61085071e+01,
     1.11448029e+01,   1.79458912e-02]), array([ -5.89070987e+01,   1.44413906e+02,  -1.00532825e+02,
     9.34450117e+00,   5.69193834e+00,   7.78017045e-02])]
```

The output is from the following code:

```
polyfit = []
for i in range(0,numberofdata):
     polyfit.append(numpy.polyfit(x,noisedsignal,i))
```

Is it considered a good method to list these results?if yes how to get each value in order after to find the squared error of each order?

Comment: Why are you doing this? It's not possible to give a single definitive answer without knowing what you're doing with your arrays (and why you're using arrays in the first place, rather than more lists).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "calling" an array?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.I edited the question.

Comment: If it is only to learn the language, continue the way you're doing it. The bigger the order of the polynomial, the better the fit. Some of the answers below have already mentioned how you can extract one of these coefficient arrays from the list.

Comment: I can agree that the bigger the polynomial the better the fit.My next step is the RMS error.But still didnt figure out how to impliment it correct and with an elegant way.I would like to start thinking in a correct way how to impliment arrays,matrixes etc. in Python.For that reason was my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine. If it's clear from the beginning how many fits you are going to do it may make sense to use a 2-dimensional array.

In any case, the result of `polyfit` can be directly used in the `numpy.polyval` function to evaluate the fitted polynomial. You could also do something like

```
for p in polyfits:
    print(" + ".join(
                      "%s x ** %s" % (coeff, len(p) - n - 1)
                      for n, coeff in enumerate(p)
                    ))
```

to print out the polynomials. There is no relevant penalty to using a list here.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

You should do something like :

> your_variable = [[-0.01819394], [-1.40744691,  0.68552951], [ 0.80998048, -2.21742739,  0.80552662], [ 22.23999663, -32.55001446,  10.44015094,   0.03673661], [ -2.85384060e+00,   2.79476778e+01,  -3.61085071e+01,
>        1.11448029e+01,   1.79458912e-02], [ -5.89070987e+01,   1.44413906e+02,  -1.00532825e+02,
>        9.34450117e+00,   5.69193834e+00,   7.78017045e-02]]

Now to retrieve some element, you just go the way you should work with native Python list(array) objects.

Like `your_variable[1][1]` will give `0.68552951` and `your_variable[4][2]` will give `-3.61085071e+01`

Answer (score -2):

You have a list that has tuples that tuples include lists. It is really not necessary. First of all if you want to define them, why in tuples?

> array([-0.01819394]) its a tuple that have a list.

Tuple processes are faster than list processes. But tuples are inmutable variables.I usually using lists, there is no big speed difference between them and you can change list elements.

> For example you want to call *0.68552951* in array([-1.40744691,  0.68552951])

```
list=[array([-0.01819394]),array([-1.40744691,  0.68552951]),...]
print (list[1][1])
```

It means second element of second element of the list.

Comment: There is no tuple to be seen here. `array([bla])` means most likely that these are numpy arrays.